# How do I prevent scrolling to the next email when I mouse scroll in mutt. mutt in Centos 7

Tags: email, mouse, mutt, scrolling, mouse-gestures

mutt in Centos 7
I write this to help others as the articles I found were a mess and did not explain properly.

**So when I am in an email in Mutt and I naturally scroll out of instinct, mutt sends me back to the previous indexed screen to the list of emails and scrolls there, it drops me out of the current email I am trying to scroll through, which is extremely frustrating.**

To Navigate my email I can:
 - **Return key** to scroll down 1 line at a time.
 - **page down/up** for 1 page at a time.
 - **home** to go to top.
 - **end** to go to bottom.
 - probably heaps of other ways, which I am happy to expand on here, please comment and I will edit/add acordingly.

But mouse scrolling is natural!

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Me it was:

login as root

```
>sudo su -
```

using nano editor (i prefer nano) edit this file in the hone directory of the user (i think)

```
>nano .muttrc
```

add these 2 lines:

```
bind pager <up> previous-line #scroll inside the message rather than the index
bind pager <down> next-line"
```

Save in nano

```
CTRL X
Y
Enter
```

do this for the user you are accessing mutt as, for me I am accessing root's emails.

**I do not know whether this breaks a different use of the scroll wheel, but for me the application behaves as I expect.**

ENJOY your mutterings!

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Page Down from going to the next email? I'd rather it just say "Scrolled to bottom of message", consistent with Page Up.

Comment: Add the line `set pager_stop = true` to .muttrc to prevent Page Down from going to the next email.

Comment: I had to use `set pager_stop = yes` (Mutt 1.10.1) but it works well. Thanks @matvore!